# Remove Git Credential-osxkeychain

Tags: git, caching, terminal, installation

I'm having major problems getting git to run on my Mac OSX10.8.2.  I installed git, and was following the tutorial [here](https://help.github.com/articles/set-up-git). I followed the step to do password caching, but now whenever I type in "git" to terminal, I get the following statement back:

```
Usage: git credential-osxkeychain <get|store|erase>
```

When I run another command like "git push", it does not return anything.

Any ideas at all on how to get this working?  All help is greatly appreciated!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just had this issue myself. I had remove my current install of git and reinstall it. Fortunately it only takes a few minutes to do this.

Go here: http://git-scm.com/downloads

Download the latest version of git. Open it, and inside you'll see a few files. Open uninstall.sh in a text editor. Go down to the block of code that reads:

```
if [ "$response" == "yes" ]; then
  sudo rm -rf /usr/local/git/
  sudo rm /etc/paths.d/git
  sudo rm /etc/manpaths.d/git
  sudo pkgutil --forget --pkgs=GitOSX\.Installer\.git[A-Za-z0-9]*\.[a-z]*.pkg
  echo "Uninstalled"
else
  echo "Aborted"
  exit 1
fi
```

You need to run each of the sudo commands inside the "if" statement, but you have to modify the first one so that the path is where your git is installed. Find this out by typing `which git` in the terminal. From here, all you have to do is install the git-whateverversion.pkg file that you downloaded (in the same folder as uninstall.sh file). Install it, and you're good to go. Follow the username and email sections again at https://help.github.com/articles/set-up-git, but this time don't do the password caching :)

Answer (score 6):

There's a simpler answer to be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16052602/disable-git-credential-osxkeychain)

```
git config --global --edit
```

Once in that file remove the [helper] section of the file.

Comment: This is a much better solution that reinstalling Git, and solves the problem.