# Git using alternate userid although git config and git remote do not reference it

Tags: git, github

I have two github ids:  javadxx and stephencompanyid.

While attempting to push to the github repo shown in the screenshot below it seems the incorrect userid were applied: the intention is to use the `javadxx` but the error message seem to indicate the other one were applied.

Here are the remote refs:

```
$git remote -v
origin  https://github.com/javadxx/jfreechart-fse (fetch)
origin  https://github.com/javadxx/jfreechart-fse (push)
```

Screenshot shows the fork was created under javadxx id:

[image]

Here is the command attempted:

```
6:40:01/jfreechart-fse $git push origin InitFromArray
remote: Permission to javadxx/jfreechart-fse.git denied to stephencompanyid.
```

The strange thing is that both the `.gitconfig` and the local `git config -l` indicate otherwise - i.e. that the `javadxx` were active.

```
jfreechart-fse $git config user.name
javadxx
16:48:04/jfreechart-fse $git config user.email
javadxx@<blah>
```

Inside `.gitconfig`:

```
[user]
    name = javadxx 
    email = javadxx@<blah>
```

I even looked inside the .git folder for any remnants of the other id:

```
grep companyname .git/*

(no results)
```

Comment: Can you try pushing to GitHub using `https`?  This should force GitHub to prompt you for a username and password thus eliminating the chance that the wrong user gets used.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen it looks like the remotes are already using https.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data used by `git config` (and in your config) file is used for creating the *author* of the commit. You can put in anything in there - it doesn't matter, there's no verification that this is actually you or any other valid address.

What you are seeing is the authentication for pushing to the server - that's handled separately by Git. Depending on your operating system, your credentials may be cached - this is likely what you're seeing here.

Git comes with a *credential helper*, which stores your Git credentials in the operating system's credential store (on Windows and on Mac OS X. Linux does not have a secure Git credential store).

To clear the stored authentication data, type the following in a terminal/shell window (hit the <kbd>ENTER</kbd> key where it says `<ENTER>`):

```
git credential reject<ENTER>
url=https://github.com<ENTER>
<ENTER>
```

This should clear the stored information, once you try to push again, it should ask for username and password again.

Alternatively, you can use your operating system's credential store (e.g. *Keychain Access* on Mac OS X) to delete the credentials manually.

More info on the credential storage here:

- https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Credential-Storage
- https://help.github.com/articles/caching-your-github-password-in-git/

Comment: Wow! You nailed it there.

Answer (score 1):

The `user.name` is for the commits. Not for the actual GitHub https session.

The account used for the GitHub session is entered on `git push`.
Or it can be part of the url:

```
git remote set-url https://javadxx@github.com/javadxx/jfreechart-fse
                           ^^^^^^^^
```

That way, a `git push` will always require javadxx's password;

Comment: The error says  `denied to stephencompanyid.`  Where did that other ID come from  : it is not included in the remote url.

Comment: @javadba it won't say that if you include the right id in the url

Comment: ah! I did not pay close enough attention. (even with the ^^^  hit me with a mallet hint)

Comment: @javadba qso do you really need a credential helper here?

Comment: Is there an alternative that avoids entering a password each time?

Comment: @javadba That was not your question. Your question was about the right user account used for GitHub.

Comment: OK so i searched a bit and found something along the line of this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16052602/disable-git-credential-osxkeychain  (and yes you have an answer on it).  I will not touch now but will consider digging more down the road.