# Credentials for GitHub 'stuck' on my other account

Tags: windows, git, github

I've been trying to push commits to GitHub using my 'real' account (`MikeTheGreat`) but no matter what I do [GitHub keeps listing them as my other account](https://github.com/MikeTheGreat/easy-kill/commits/master) (`StudentDemoAccount`).  I've been able to clear my credentials (as evidenced by the fact that when I try to do a `git push` it asks me for my username and password again), but when I type in my MikeTheGreat account info the commit is listed on GitHub as being from the StudentDemoAccount.

I've gone through a bunch of pages, including:

- [Git using alternate userid although git config and git remote do not
  reference
  it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31777761/git-using-alternate-userid-although-git-config-and-git-remote-do-not-reference-i)
- [Remove credentials from
  Git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15381198/remove-credentials-from-git)
- many other pages (both here, on GitHub.com, and elsewhere).

I'm able to force Git to re-authenticate me (by re-generating the GitHub Personal Access Token), but whenever I give it my MikeTheGreat credentials it still lists the commit as coming from the StudentDemoAccount.

I'm on Windows 10, and am using the command-line git tools on a CMD.exe.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like GitHub uses the `user.email` git config key to determine which account the commit should be tied to.  Changing that fixed the problem:

`git config --replace-all user.email <email address for MikeTheGreat>`

It's worth pointing out that [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31780721/250610) specifically says that

> The data used by git config (and in your config) file is used for creating the author of the commit. You can put in anything in there - it doesn't matter, there's no verification that this is actually you or any other valid address.

I think they're talking about specifically about `user.name`, but it was late and I read it as 'anything about the user that I set via `user.*`'.