# How do I stop Git Bash from opening the Team Services (was VSO) sign-in window on push or pull?

Tags: git, bash, azure-devops

I have a Git project that is hosted on visualstudio.com. Whenever I initiate a `git push` or `git pull`, it always pops open the Team Services login window, which I then have to close, since logging in from that window takes longer and requires a redirect. Then I can use Git Bash to enter my credentials and it works.

This didn't happen until recently when I updated my Git install version. How do I stop the window from popping up every time? [Here's a screenshot](http://prntscr.com/c7h8ht) of the window that pops up.

Comment: Does `git config --get core.askpass` show anything?

Comment: No, it just takes the command and does nothing.

Comment: What is the value of `$SSH_ASKPASS` and `$GIT_ASKPASS`? (You should be able to `echo` these from the Git Bash prompt.)

Answer (score 2):

That window is opened by [Microsoft's Git Credential Manager](https://github.com/Microsoft/Git-Credential-Manager-for-Windows) and is useful if you use [two-factor authentication (2FA) with GitHub](https://help.github.com/articles/securing-your-account-with-two-factor-authentication-2fa/) or [MFA with VSTS](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/multi-factor-authentication/).  It is now installed by default along with Git for Windows.

If you wish to disable this, you can turn off Microsoft's Git Credential Manager.  Simply run:

```
git config --global --unset credential.helper
```

Comment: This didn't do anything. It still pops up.

Comment: Can you post the results of `git config --list` in your question?

Comment: @EdwardThomson Is the `.` at the end of that command superfluous?

Comment: @ScottWeldon That was a typo - corrected.  Thanks!  :D

Comment: @Longblog Can you try this again now that it's been corrected?

Comment: I tried again and it still popped up. So, I ran the `git config --list` command you mentioned and saw credential.helper=manager was still set. I googled that and found [this page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16052602/disable-git-credential-osxkeychain). I ran all three commands and ran into a permissions error on the third one. So I opened that file location, changed permissions, opened it in Sublime Text and deleted the credential helper line. It's fixed now! It's not popping up anymore, annoying me every time I have to pull or push. Thanks for your assistance guys.

Edit: formatting

Answer (score 1):

According to the [gitcredentials documentation](//git-scm.com/docs/gitcredentials):

> Without any credential helpers defined, Git will try the following strategies to ask the user for usernames and passwords:
>
> 1. If the `GIT_ASKPASS` environment variable is set, the program specified by the variable is invoked. A suitable prompt is provided to the program on the command line, and the user’s input is read from its standard output.
> 2. Otherwise, if the `core.askPass` configuration variable is set, its value is used as above.
> 3. Otherwise, if the `SSH_ASKPASS` environment variable is set, its value is used as above.
> 4. Otherwise, the user is prompted on the terminal.

Thus, to force option 4 to take effect, you need to ensure that the three other values are not set.

For 1 and 3, you should be able to do e.g. `SSH_ASKPASS=''`. (To automate this, add that line to `C:\Users\<user>\.bashrc`.) For 2, do `git config --unset-all core.askPass`.

---

As you can tell from the first line of the quote, this only applies if you don't have any credential helpers defined. If you do, then you can unset them as described in [EdwardThomson's answer](//stackoverflow.com/a/39028773/2747593).

Comment: I followed these instructions and it's still popping up.

Comment: If this doesn't work, then [EdwardThomson's answer](//stackoverflow.com/a/39028773/2747593) should be correct.