# How to disable git-credential-osxkeychain

Tags: git, aws-cli

I am trying to set saml2aws to provide temporary credentials for AWS services, specifically Codecommit.
I have managed to install AWS CLI and saml2aws and got the credentials. But when current credentials expired I have faced 403.
After a short dig, I discovered that the problem is `osxkeychain`

I set configurations as follow for `--local`, `--global` and `--system`

```
[credential]
    UseHttpPath = true
    helper = !aws --profile saml codecommit credential-helper $@
```

However, in my repository when I run

```
git config -l
```

The response reads as;

```
credential.helper=osxkeychain
credential.helper=!aws --profile saml codecommit credential-helper $@
credential.usehttppath=true
.
.
.
credential.helper=!aws --profile saml codecommit credential-helper $@
.
.
.
credential.usehttppath=true
credential.helper=!aws --profile saml codecommit credential-helper $@
```

The closest thing was [disable git credential-osxkeychain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16052602/disable-git-credential-osxkeychain) but didn't help.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can have multiple credential helpers configured in each config file, which explains why it has still there after you ran that config command at each level - you've just added a new config line rather than replacing the old one.

To see which config file it's in, run

```
git config --list --show-origin
```

Then you can remove it by manually editing the file.

If you don't have perms to file it's configured in, you can manually edit a tighter config file to look like:

```
[credential]
    helper =
    helper = !aws --profile saml codecommit credential-helper $@
```

The blank helper stops it falling back to helpers configured at higher levels of config

Comment: Worked! I actually replaced the credential.helper in each level (`--local`,`--global`,`--system`) but the gitconfig file located in /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/share/git-core/ doesn't seem to be effected. now I manually edited that file to match above and worked.
Thank you very much!

Comment: Wooooow, the other posts have so many upvotes and this one is the best answer :)