# Git and OSX Messages (causes conflict)

Tags: git, macos-high-sierra

My messages app on Mac OSX 10.13.6 works when I first start my computer up. However, as soon as I `git push`, I can no longer send messages through OSX's messages app. I get `not delivered` errors. I need to restart my computer to get it working again.

What could be causing this?

Comment: I suppose it didn't work, then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just for testing, check (when you have the iMessage issue) the output of `git config credential.helper`.

If you see `osxkeychain`, try and (again for testing) to [disable that helper](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16052884/6309), and see iMessage works again then.

To add more: if you are pushing to a remote repository using an HTTPS URL, then the credentials (username/password) are cached by Git using a host service ([Windows Credential Manager](https://github.com/Microsoft/Git-Credential-Manager-for-Windows) for Windows, [Keychain for Mac](https://help.github.com/en/articles/updating-credentials-from-the-osx-keychain))

But, that might interfere with iMessage, preventing it to access to your iCloud credentials and therefore disconnecting your from iCloud.
Hence the "not delivered" error messages.

As a test, deactivating the Git credential caching setting can help validate that potential issue.

Then you can try and reactivating it as a git global setting, or a repo per repository basis.

Comment: git config --local credential.helper and git config --global credential.helper, returned nothing.  However, git config --system credential.helper did return osxkeychain. So it does not look like osxkeychain is running in my local folder.

Comment: @user Yes, actually, it would run for *all* repositories, for all users. So my answer stands in it's general idea.

Comment: I will try to unset and let you know.

Comment: I think it worked. I will continue testing in the next few day. Thank you!