# Git clone only works with git:// and not with https://

Tags: git, gitversion

When trying to clone with "https://" always getting error of "fatal: read error: Invalid argument".  BUt the same is working when i replace the url with "git://"

$ git clone https://github.com/DiyanTonchev/Issue-Tracking-System.git
Cloning into 'Issue-Tracking-System'...
fatal: read error: Invalid argument

When I try with "git clone git://github.com/DiyanTonchev/Issue-Tracking-System.git". i can able to clone properly

Comment: This is likely an error coming from https two-factor authentication. Could you check the output of 'git credential-osxkeychain'?

Comment: Did you have a look at this: [HTTPS cloning errors](https://help.github.com/en/articles/https-cloning-errors)?

Comment: I found the answer with **git credential-osxkeychain**.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Try the **git credential-osxkeychain** outputs.

For me i have removed the unwanted Url configuration from  the file **.gitconfig**.

You can find the file location using following command.

'$ git config --show-origin --get credential.helper'.

For more information you can refer the following link ([disable git credential-osxkeychain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16052602/disable-git-credential-osxkeychain))

Answer (score 0):

I tried the git clone of the repo you mentioned with https, and it works fine. I am on Mac. Are you trying on windows? Did you try with git bash or Cygwin?
Also, avoid the "Control + V" for paste on cmd, as it appends hidden "^?"
Sometimes, there is also corrupt installation, so may be you can try re-install.

Comment: I am Using **git Bash** in windows. I also tried reinstalling and typing instead of copy. but the result is same