# A keychain cannot be found to store "<username>"

Tags: git, macos, keychain

**Issue:** I have a bash script that builds an application. The complete application requires many (50+) "git clone" calls to assemble the pieces from different repositories. Although I do not get username/password challenges from "git clone", the Mac displays an ***A keychain cannot be found to store "<USERNAME>."***, alert as shown below.

For the bash script to proceed, a mouse click is required for each "git clone call." Would like to remove this but what type of keychain does git need?

[Keychain Not Found](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7d3l3.png).

Results of the buttons:

- **Cancel**: Click the mouse for each clone and the script will succeed but no bio breaks while it builds.
- **Reset To Defaults**: Wipes out logins and does not prevent the alerts.

Versions:

- Git: 2.31
- MacOS: Big Sur 11.6

Comment: Git itself does not know anything about keychains, and does not create pop-up windows, but Git *does* need (and hence use) *credentials* to do http/https cloning. To get those credentials, Git will run a *credential helper*. You can configure which credential helper to use. On macOS you'll generally run the `osxkeychain` based credential helper (a separate program); see [this GitHub documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/get-started/getting-started-with-git/updating-credentials-from-the-macos-keychain). See also [this SO Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16052602/1256452).

Comment: In this particular case, you probably want to figure out how to configure the OSX keychain system so that it knows where to store these, or not to store these, rather than completely disabling it, but that's not something I can tell you about.

Comment: Yes, the goal is to not disable the keychain system but rather to squash to the "squeaky" alters. 

The alert unfortunately only seems to tell me it has got something to store (my username) but it cannot find a keychain to store it in. So far I have not been able to figure out what the keychain needs to look like.

Answer (score -1):

I'm struggling with the same issue. So far, my attempts to overwrite the `credential.helper=osxkeychain` git config value have failed -- even if I delete the .gitconfig that it comes from, it sticks around like a ghost. Would love to know if you're able to move past this, and I'll share if I find a solution as well.