# git push origin main stuck forever not upload anything

Tags: git, github, github-api

git push origin main stuck forever not upload anything.

I have run following steps

```
        git init
        git add -A
        git commit -a -m "update"
        git branch -M main
        git remote add origin https://github.com/hoogw/j2t.git
        git push origin main
```

Eveything runs well, until last step, it stuck there forever,
and not uploading  anything.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Run `git remote set-url origin git@github.com:hoogw/j2t.git` and then again `git push origin main`

Comment: I agree. The mistake was saying `git remote add origin https:...`. Do _not_ use `https` to talk to GitHub via Git.

Comment: It may be the issue that the credentials manager cannot be reached. May be something along these lines? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16052602/how-to-disable-osxkeychain-as-credential-helper-in-git-config

Answer (score 0):

You can check if your git can actually access GitHub remote (in case the problem is network) by fetching the remote first

```
git fetch origin
```

If it can fetch without error, then you can push your commit with verbose flag to see if there is any issue while git push

```
git push --verbose origin main
```

Answer (score -1):

git remote set-url origin git@github.com:hoogw/j2t.git

without use https:// does not work

[image]

I think it is because of github's bug or credential manager downtime, I did not do anything, after 1 week, github fixed their bug, I repeat the same steps as befor, it works without any issue.
It must be github fixed their bugs(credential manager), I did not do anything. This question should be closed.
Below is working steps.

[image]

Comment: "This question should be closed." So close it. There is a Delete button under your questions. Click it!